Task execution role while using terraform ecs module
I'm using terraform ecs module in the form when service and container definitions defined inside the ecs module resourse.
It works for me, but if I add "task_role_arn", the I get error:
  Error: Invalid for_each argument
  │ 
  │   on .terraform/modules/ecs/modules/service/main.tf line 531, in module 
  "container_definition":
  │  531:   for_each = { for k, v in var.container_definitions : k => v if 
  local.create_task_definition && try(v.create, true) }
  │     ├────────────────
  │     │ local.create_task_definition is true
  │     │ var.container_definitions will be known only after apply

This is my terraform
module "ecs" {
 source = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws"

 cluster_name = "my_company-backend"

 cluster_configuration = {
   execute_command_configuration = {
     logging = "OVERRIDE"
     log_configuration = {
       cloud_watch_log_group_name = "/aws/ecs/backend"
    }
  }
}

 fargate_capacity_providers = {
   FARGATE = {
     default_capacity_provider_strategy = {
       weight = 100
     }
   }

 }

services = {
  "my_company-backend" = {
  cpu    = 2048
  memory = 8192

  # Container definition(s)
  container_definitions = {

    "my_company-backend-node" = {
      cpu       = 2048
      memory    = 8192
      essential = true
      image     = local.backend_image
      task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.backend_role.arn
      port_mappings = [
        {
          name          = "my_company-backend-node"
          containerPort = 3000
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ]
      health_check = {
        command     = ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:3000/api/health || exit 1"]
        interval    = 30
        timeout     = 5
        retries     = 3
        startPeriod = 0
      }

      readonly_root_filesystem  = false
      cloudwatch_log_group_name = "/ecs/backend_ecs"
      enable_cloudwatch_logging = true
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          "awslogs-group"         = "/ecs/backend_ecs"
          "awslogs-region"        = "${local.region}"
          "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "ecs"
        }
      }
      "secrets" : local.secrets
      "environment" : local.backend_env
    }

  }

  load_balancer = {
    service = {
      target_group_arn = module.alb.target_groups["backend_nodejs"].arn
      container_name   = "my_company-backend-node"
      container_port   = 3000
    }
  }

  subnet_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnets
  security_group_rules = {
    alb_ingress_3000 = {
      type                     = "ingress"
      from_port                = 3000
      to_port                  = 3000
      protocol                 = "tcp"
      description              = "Service port"
      source_security_group_id = module.alb.security_group_id
    }
    egress_all = {
      type        = "egress"
      from_port   = 0
      to_port     = 0
      protocol    = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
       }
     }
   }
 }

}

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that TF is trying to evaluate the container_definitions variable before it's fully known, particularly because it depends on dynamic values such as the task_role_arn.
It's difficult to recommend a solution without knowing your TF File Structure. You can probably try one of these things:

Ensure task_role_arn is known before usage i.e., move aws_iam_role.backend_role resource creation before the module declaration.
Use depends_on (if applicable).

